# How to display a mplfinance chart in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, mplfinance

When I execute this code I have 2 frames. Is there any way to display this in one root frame?

```py
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("candle")
root.geometry('600x550')

def candle():

    file  = 'BTC-USD.csv'

    data = pd.read_csv(file)

    print(data.info())
    data.Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Date)
    data = data.set_index('Date')
    print(data)
    mpf.plot(data, type='candle', mav=(20),volume=True, style='yahoo')

button = Button(root, text="grapg", comand=candle())
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Below is my output of above code:

[image: My Output]

Comment: Create a canvas and overlap the chart on the canvas. This should do the job. Not exactly similar to what I said but you can refer this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-embed-matplotlib-charts-in-tkinter-gui/

Comment: Look at panels..    https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/panels.ipynb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach that I have seen work most often is to call `mpf.plot()` first, outside of tkinter, with [kwarg `returnfig=True`](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/wiki/Acessing-mplfinance-Figure-and-Axes-objects#1-set-returnfigtrue-when-calling-mpfplot--this-is-the-preferred-way).   Then use the figure returned by `mpf.plot()` to create your tkinter canvas, something like this:

```py
fig, axlist = mpf.plot(data,type='candle',mav=(20),volume=True, 
                       style='yahoo',returnfig=True)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig)
```

See also

- https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/440#issuecomment-911653228
- https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/wiki/TkInter-Example
- https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/304

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! I needed that returnfig=True in order to embed the figure in tkinter. It is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for all your hard work.